# Undefined eager-loaded model in Laravel Echo event

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-echo

I'm using Laravel Echo to broadcast events from the server to the client.

The application is a forum, where users can create posts in topics.

Here is the controlled method code where the new post is created, and the event dispatched.

```
$post = Post::create([
  'user_id' => 1,
  'topic_id' => request('topic_id'),
  'body' => request('body'),
]);

// Fetch the post we've just created, with the relationships this time
$post = Post::with('user', 'topic')->find($post->id);

// Broadcast the event
event(new PostCreated($post));
```

Here is the event class :

```
class PostCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  public $post;

  public function __construct(Post $post)
  {
    $this->post = $post;
  }

  public function broadcastOn()
  {
    return new Channel('topics.' . $this->post->topic_id);
  }
}
```

Finally, here is where the event is intercepted in the front-end :

```
Echo.channel('topics.' + this.topic.id)
  .listen('PostCreated', (e) => {
    this.posts.push(e.post);
  });
```

The problem is that I can't seem to access the `user` property from the `listen()` method on the front-end.

```
console.log(e.post.user) // Undefined
```

If I do a `console.log()` of the post, I can see the properties of the `Post` (user_id, topic_id, body, created_at, updated_at) but it's not showing the `user` or `topic` properties that were eager-loaded in the controller, before the event was sent.

Those properties **are accessible** from the event class itself :

```
// In the __construct() method of the PostCreated event
echo $this->post->user->name; // Works, the name is echo'd
```

... but somehow are not sent to the front-end when the event is broadcasted.

How can I make sure that the `user` and `topic` properties are sent to the client, along with the post itself?